# Superclass mismatch for serializer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, serialization, associations, active-model-serializers

The serializer for `Article` has two nested serializers: `Author` and `Chapter`. The latter two also have their own individual serializers. I'm using the active_model_serializer gem.

```
# The nested serializer
class Api::V1::ArticleSerializer < Api::V1::SerializerWithSessionMetadata
  attributes :id, ...
  has_many :authors, root: :authors_attributes
  has_many :chapters, through: :authors, root: :chapters_attributes

  class Api::V1::AuthorSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
    ...
  end
  class Api::V1::ChapterSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
    ...
  end
end

# The two individual serializers
class Api::V1::AuthorSerializer < Api::V1::SerializerWithSessionMetadata
  ...
end

class Api::V1::ChapterSerializer < Api::V1::SerializerWithSessionMetadata
  ...
end
```

**Problem:** I currently sometimes get an error while other times I don't (while making the same server request). If the error happens, I restart the server, make the same request, and the error isn't there.

> superclass mismatch for class ArticleSerializer

The error refers to `class Api::V1::AuthorSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer` in the nested serializer. It seems to particularly happen when creating a new `author` record. This uses:

```
author = @article.authors.build(create_params)
if author.save
  render json: @article, status: :created
end
```

So this method's `render` line calls on the nested serializer after created an author. What could be the cause of this behavior?

Is the line `class Api::V1::AuthorSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer` correct or should it perhaps inherit from something else? Perhaps it sees the `Author`s nested serializer higher in hierarchy because it inherits from a higher serializer than its individual serializer does. And as a result uses the nested version when it should use its individual version.

If I let the nested version inherit from `Api::V1::SerializerWithSessionMetadata` instead, then the error is gone. However, the disadvantage then is that it repeats the attributes from the meta serializer for each individual author and chapter in the article serializer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that problem is in **namespace** for nested serializer. When you create a class within other one, actually, you create a class inside other one's namespace. And inner class doesn't inherit anything from outer one except its name. So your **inner** *AuthorSerializer* can be called as `Api::V1::ArticleSerializer::Api::V1::AuthorSerializer`
So try to rename your classes

```
class Api::V1::ArticleSerializer < Api::V1::SerializerWithSessionMetadata
  ...

  class AuthorSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
    ...
  end

  class ChapterSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
    ...
  end
end

# The two individual serializers
class Api::V1::AuthorSerializer < Api::V1::SerializerWithSessionMetadata
  ...
end

class Api::V1::ChapterSerializer < Api::V1::SerializerWithSessionMetadata
  ...
end
```

Comment: Yes, thanks, the problem was indeed that the nested serializers had the same name as their non-nested ones.